# Netbeans 12.6 on Linux. Java source code editor misbehaving

Tags: java, netbeans, editor

Running NetBeans 12.6 on Linux Mint.
When editing Java source files, the editor isn't behaving as expected.
Placing the cursor at the end of a text line and hitting return causes the editor to insert a new line and then place the cursor at its start, rather than under the first non white-space character of the line above.
So I have to enter code that is at the left margin and then use the source formatting option to align things correctly.
Earlier releases of NetBeans behave as expected, as do other IDE's.
C++ source files edit correctly.
I'm running this version of NetBeans on two PC's, both exhibit this behaviour.
Non of the editor Formatting options (under Tools/Options/Formatting tab) seem relevant. Also, the Preview pane is blank for most of the Java Categories.
Seems like a bug in NetBeans 12.6, but I can't find any reference to this on the web.
Anyone else experiencing this? Thanks.

Comment: If you think this is a bug in NetBeans 12.6 then [create a NetBeans bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues/NETBEANS-6298?filter=allopenissues).

Comment: It seemed a bit early to say it's a bug. It seems a possibility this is a formatting setting I've not yet discovered, rather than a bug. However, if I don't hear from anyone who has experienced this, and found the fix, then I will report it as a bug.

Comment: But you have explicitly stated in the question "**Seems like a bug in NetBeans 12.6**".

Comment: Yes, 'seems' means I'm not sure. I was waiting until I could be more sure before pestering the NetBeans support team. I would be grateful to learn if you have experience of this version of NetBeans on Linux developing Java apps. If so, do you get this behaviour. If you haven't anything meaningful to contribute, I'd rather we didn't continue this dialogue.

Comment: My comment was meaningful. People aren't going to bother helping you here if you state that the issue "Seems like a bug in NetBeans 12.6", and your entire post strongly implies that NetBeans is the cause of the problem. You are not "pestering" NetBeans by reporting it. If it is a bug they will appreciate knowing about the problem.

Comment: Check that you have nb-javac Java editing support library installed in installed plugins with show details checked. Check if View -> IDE Log has any errors or exceptions.  Close all projects , restart and create a new project just to see if the editor failure is related to your project.

Comment: Some other people have experienced the same, seems to be a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70592099/5078385

Comment: Thank you WillShackleford and acm.
The nb-javac Java editing support is library installed.
I've tried closing all projects, exited the IDE and created a new Java Project. Sadly, the problem remains.
The output of View->IDE has a few WARNINGS, this ones seems relevant, but I've not found how to fix it.
WARNING [org.netbeans.core.modules]: the modules [org.netbeans.modules.java.editor.lib, org.netbeans.modules.xml.text] use org.netbeans.modules.editor.deprecated.pre65formatting which is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug has been reported here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-6281.

Current workaround is to downgrade to version 12.5.

Comment: Thanks. I also reported this as a bug a couple of days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a Windows 10 computer.

It turned out that Netbeans 12.6 with JDK 8 caused this problem.
So instead of downgrading Netbeans, you can upgrade your JDK (I installed JDK 16).
After upgrading the JDK the problem was solved.

Note after installing a newer JDK and adding the platform to Netbeans, I had to tell Netbeans to use the new JDK by changing the path of the JDK folder in the Netbeans configuration file;

```
...\Program Files\NetBeans-12.6\netbeans\etc\netbeans.conf
```