# Netbeans isn't automatically identing (Java)

Tags: java, netbeans, indentation

I have a university project where I must code a Java App. Since we learned java using Netbeans as an IDE, I decided to code the app using this IDE.

I had never experienced this bug on my previous computer. Right now, when I open "{ }" after writing a function or any other block, the line after when pressing "return" isn't indented, and pressing "tab" doesn't do anything.

```java
public class App {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("");
code
impossible
to
indent...

    }
    
}
```

Maybe, someone know what the problem is ?

thanks :D

Comment: It has been asked before, seems to be a bug: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70582625/5078385

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems there is a bug in NetBeans.

See this link for more details
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-6281

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well and solved it by upgrading the JDK version that Netbeans uses. Check my answer here: [Netbeans 12.6 on Linux. Java source code editor misbehaving](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70696001/5594646)